# How to add custom meta tag in Liferay generated page

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-theme, liferay-velocity

I need do put different META tags in different Liferay generated pages.

Example

```
<!-- Page1 -->
<META name="test1" content="content1" /> 

<!-- Page2 -->
<META name="test2" content="content2" />
```

How can I achieve this?

**Update**

I cannot be more specific because this is the simple problem but I think "Liferay 6.0 doesn't support custom meta tags" can be the answer.

Comment: Can you be more precise about what you are trying to achieve? Liferay 6.0 doesn't support custom meta tags and context would help in figuring out an elegant solution.

Answer (score 2):

I have to be a bit vague as I don't have all resources available at the moment:

- In page management you can set extra meta data per page
- You can change your theme to include the required metadata.
- If you need it available/configurable on the page level, there are custom fields that you can define. If I recall correctly they are also available for pages. I don't know if there's a UI for it, but you can extend the "Manage Pages" UI to include these custom pages or provide independent settings if required (e.g. a portlet on each page, visible only to those having access to that data)
- If a whole group (community/organization) has the same metadata, you might deploy [variations of a theme](https://www.liferay.com/web/olaf.kock/blog/-/blogs/theme-development%3a-choosing-your-parent) or combine them [into a common "virtual" site](https://www.liferay.com/web/olaf.kock/blog/-/blogs/control-content-permissions-based-on-the-page-the-content-is-published-on)